# Return Javascript value inside Html from another JS

Tags: javascript, html, function, nested

I need ur help i know this is a silly question but am not able to solve it ...sorrry :(

I have one javascript file  welcome.js
in that i have

```
    function alert()
    {
    return 10;
    }
```

I have another html file welcome.html in which am invoking the welcome.js file

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript src="welcome.js"></script>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
     var x = alert();
    return x;
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <input type="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="Show alert box">
```

I keep on getting this error in mozilla console

Timestamp: 5/28/2013 9:56:47 PM
Error: NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments [nsIDOMWindow.alert]

Comment: @acdcjunior It can, http://jsfiddle.net/G5xKB/

Comment: @Niklas good catch! (deleted my comment as it was misleading)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

alert function name shouldn't be overriden, because in that case if you use

`alert(something)`

you will call to your new function and not to the dialog function

You have 2 options:

- put another name to your function alert
- when you need to call to dialog function use `window.alert(something)` to differentiate

Comment: It isn't reserved, it just never is getting overwritten.

Comment: @Niklas this is a best replication of the problem, and doesnt work: http://jsfiddle.net/G5xKB/1/

Answer (score 5):

Your javascript (welcome.js) isn't getting loaded do to the syntax error in your script tag. You are missing the `"` quote after `text/javascript`.

The `alert();` is calling `window.alert()` which requires an argument to be passed in Firefox (doesn't for example in Chrome). As your own welcome.js never gets loaded (due to the syntax error), it never ends up rewriting the global alert() function.

Answer (score 0):

You can not override `window.alert()` function, try the below:

```
 function test()
    {
    return 10;
    }
```

Then in you html use `test()`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script type="text/javascript src="welcome.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
 var x = test();
return x;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="button" onclick="myFunction();" value="Show alert box">
```